# import environ could not be resolved pylance when using venv

Tags: django, python-venv

I'm new in Python/Django and I'm trying to create a live app.
I did create the django project first, then realized I should do this in a venv. So I created the venv within my project folder. I managed to get my PostgreSQL db connected, and since I'm trying to keep my stuff secure, I'm storing my DB password in a global variable.

```
import environ

from pathlib import Path

env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()
```

My problem is that I keep getting the error:

> import environ could not be resolved pylance

in my `settings.py` file and I've no idea why. I think I've set up my venv correctly and placed it in my project folder.

Is something wrong with my interpreter? I'd really like some help with this please.

[image: this is how my files are laid out]

This is the error I'm seeing:

[image: error]

I seem to be inside my venv:

[image: Inside venv]

I'm able to run my app just fine and update my database no problems. which I'm thinking shouldn't work if there really is an issue with how my venv is setup?

I've tried everything I can think of. Made another venv and played around with it. Only thing I'm stuck on is making sure my interpreter is correct. how can I be sure I'm using the right interpreter? When I try to manually select an interpreter, I don't see any that imply it's in my venv:
[image: example]

Comment: Structure seems alright, but you are not using your venv. Please, refer to VSCode documentation on [how to manually specify an interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter)

Comment: Also, for future reference, when asking questions involving folder structures, it is better to represent it like in this [question / answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147467/is-there-a-good-way-to-represent-file-structure-in-a-question-answer), rather than an image.

Comment: @Niko apologies, thanks for the heads up. I've solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I was just using the wrong path when selecting my interpreter manually.

I right clicked on the appropriate Python3.10 interpreter file and copied the Path url. then pasted it right into the command palette to manually set the interpreter. that refreshed vscode and removed the warning.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is somehow old and solved, but just for the record: sometimes just refreshing VS Code will do the job, in fact it may be just a misunderstanding by VS Code itself. After pressing `Ctrl + Shift + P`:

```
>Reload Window
```